# Is CPSR C flag defined when performing logic operations with immediate value?

Tags: arm

for example `movs r0, #immediate`
Will the C flag be unchanged, undefined, zero or the last rotated bit?

Comment: this is well defined in the arm documentation...

Comment: A very good question indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusingly, it depends on both the instruction encoding and the constant involved. For the 16-bit Thumb encoding that use a simple immediate, APSR.C is always untouched.

For the ARM/Thumb-2 encodings using modified immediates, it depends on the expansion of the constant. Quoting from the ARMv7 ARM, "A5.2.4 Modified immediate constants in ARM instructions":

> **Carry out**
>
> A logical instruction with the rotation field set to `0b0000` does not affect APSR.C. Otherwise, a logical flag-setting instruction sets APSR.C to the value of bit[31] of the modified immediate constant.

Thumb-2 is similar, but with a slightly more complex definition - essentially, constants which involve rotation of the 8-bit field affect the carry flag, although those involving replication of it don't.

To illustrate all that, some examples:

```
  Constant    APSR.C
         #0  unchanged
      #0xFF  unchanged
     #0xFF0  0
#0xF000000F  1
#0xFF00FF00  unchanged (Thumb-2 only)
```

Comment: Excellent! I was curious about this myself.